# Can the Ruby HTTPI library be configured to follow redirects?

Tags: ruby, savon, httpi

I am using the [Savon](http://savonrb.com/) library which in turn uses [HTTPI](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi), but *HTTPI* considers only HTTP status codes 200..299 as successful. Unfortunately, the SOAP server I am connecting to uses *HTTP 302 Found* to redirect its clients to other URLs. Is there a way I can configure *HTTPI* to follow HTTP redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading Wasabi code I found [this line](https://github.com/savonrb/wasabi/blob/2739bab71bfe4e8de51e62ca9309bc214c309ddc/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb#L38), which calls [this line](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi/blob/bd2981d3a9d24c0263e341ce7c4ad2f689cef726/lib/httpi/response.rb#L29), which calls [this line](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi/blob/bd2981d3a9d24c0263e341ce7c4ad2f689cef726/lib/httpi/response.rb#L16), so I think you can resolve with a brutal but effective constant redefinition:

```
HTTPI::Response::SuccessfulResponseCodes = HTTPI::Response::SuccessfulResponseCodes.to_a << 302
```

You can safely ignore the constant redefinition warning (you can use `Kernel.silence_warnings{ ... }`).

Anyway, I suggest you to open an issue to [httpi](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi); I think it should be the expected behaviour

Comment: Close, but it doesn't exactly solve the issue. Now instead of an `Savon::HTTP:Error`, I get an `Savon::SOAP::InvalidResponseError`.

Comment: :-/ however this is the right way; I think you should start from the line which gives you the error and debug it

Comment: f.ardelian, did you resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the 'follow_redirect= true' on the request object.

```
    request = HTTPI::Request.new
    request.follow_redirect= true
    ...
```

Just had this same issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this as I did from a Google search. Savon 2.11 supports this with a global configuration value on the client:

```
follow_redirects: true
```

Comment: Thanks!
Note that this is not documented, but you can see it in the code here: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/3814eace61050e08aa74aa292a92b88419fc403f/lib/savon/request.rb#L49-L54